# Stop refresh after click button ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want the page stop refresh after I click the button

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btneqview" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CCSEQID")%>' OnClientClick="btneqview_Command" OnCommand="btneqview_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CCSEQID") %>'>
```

Code behind :

```
Protected Sub btneqview_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)
     Dim eqid As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
     Dim url As String = "MasterlistEquipmentDetails.aspx"
     Dim s As String = "window.open('" & url & "?" & "eqid=" & eqid & "', 'popup_window', 'width=1150,height=650,left=10,top=10,resizable=no');"
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "script", s, True)
End Sub
```

However, whenever I press the button, the entire page gets refreshed.
Does anyone have a solution to this, or is it really impossible?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `asp:Button` or other server control, it will always do a post back, which you cannot avoid.  change the button into `<input type='button' />` and just call the function in the click event of the button you want to invoke.

But if by any chance you may try adding `AutoPostback = false` in your asp button.  But I'm not sure if this will work for you.  But your best option is replacing your button into a `<input type='button'>`